# Is there any way to have a wordpress multi domain setup with shared post and templates and so on?

Tags: php, wordpress

I wonder if there is any way to have only one wordpress instant which has 2 different domains (one main domain and one subdomain). The content of the domains should be different but also share pages and templates and posts. E.g. a page "employees" should be the same for both domains.

I have already set up a WordPress network and so the multi-domain setup works but unfortunately pages and posts and templates are separated. There are plugins which mirror e.g. posts also on the other domain but here is then again the problem that I have saved the post 2 times.

Comment: You can probably set up the templates to be the same (you could always symlink both to the same template folder, if nothing else), but the posts will be separate, which is the point of a Wordpress multisite. That's basically having two different sites, but with a shared admin/install. You will need to write some code that syncs that page on both sites, like if you update that page on one site, you need to update the other site. I'm not sure, but there might be some plugin that can do it for you?

Comment: I agree with @M.Eriksson the idea of a multisite is to separate the content, while using the same application.

However you could create a function which does this (heck you might already have a plugin for this). I'll add my idea as a separate comment.

Comment: You should ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer. But be careful! The multisite stuff in WordPress is quite intricate. While modding it is possible, you may find it's hard to get right.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you already have a plugin which can do this, without any coding, but i'm not familiar with them.

An idea would be to hook onto the save_post action and push the newly created post to the different blogs.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'post_to_multiple_sites' ) ) {
    add_action( 'save_post', 'post_to_multiple_sites', 20, 2 );

    function post_to_multiple_sites($original_id, $original_post) {
        
        // To prevent publishing revisions
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return $original_id;
        }

        // We only want to mess around with a post that has been published
        if( 'publish' !== get_post_status( $original_post ) ) {
            return $original_id;
        }

        // prevent "Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level reached"
        remove_action( 'save_post', __FUNCTION__ );


        /**
         * If i'm correct, when creating a network, each site/blog receive an ID. 
         * You can set these hardcoded, or create a function that returns an array of the blog id's.
         * 
         * If you only have a couple of sites, I would maintain this manually. Otherwise create a function to
         * gather all the ID's and return it as an array (up to you).
         */
        $blog_ids = [2, 3];     

        $post_data = [
            'post_author' => $original_post->post_author,
            'post_date' => $original_post->post_date,
            'post_modified' => $original_post->post_modified,
            'post_content' => $original_post->post_content,
            'post_title' => $original_post->post_title,
            'post_excerpt' => $original_post->post_excerpt,
            'post_status' => 'publish', // new post will be set to published
            'post_name' => $original_post->post_name,
            'post_type' => $original_post->post_type,
        ];


            // Gather the post meta & terms
            $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $original_id, 'category', array( 'fields' => 'slugs' ) );
            $post_meta = get_post_custom( $original_id );

            foreach ($blog_ids as $blog_id) {
                switch_to_blog($blog_id);    // https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_blog/
                
                // IN case a post with the same slug exists, don't do anything.
                // Or maybe create a new post with slug-name-2...up to you.
                if ( get_posts( [ 'name' => $post_data[ 'post_name' ], 'post_type' => $post_data[ 'post_type' ], 'post_status' => 'publish' ] ) ) {
                    restore_current_blog();
                    continue;
                }

                $inserted_post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );
                wp_set_object_terms( $inserted_post_id, $post_terms, 'category', false );

                foreach ( $post_meta as $meta_key => $meta_values) {
                    // we do not need these redirects
                    if( '_wp_old_slug' === $meta_key ) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    foreach ( $meta_values as $meta_value ) {
                        add_post_meta( $inserted_post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
                    }
                }

                restore_current_blog();
            }
    }
}
```

It became a bigger function than I expected and honestly don't know if you should go this route. Your safest bet is to try and find a plugin that handles this for you. But you can use this piece of code and extend it obviously to your needs

**Make sure to read the comments I added. These are important!**